# Loading Rows and Columns Dynamically in Google Chart Table

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm trying to add columns and rows dynamically as i get them from user. Sofar i am testing it out like:

```
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            seriesName[0] = 'Name';
            seriesName[1] = 'Age';

            for (var i = 0; i < seriesName.length; i++) {
                data.addColumn('string', seriesName[i]);
            }

            seriesData[0] = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5';
            for (var i = 0; i < seriesData.length; i++) {
                if (seriesData[i] != null) {
                    var sData = new Array();
                    sData = seriesData[i].split(',');
                    /*for (a in sData) {
                        sData[a] = parseInt(sData[a], 10);
                    }*/
                }
                var data = JSON.parse('[' + sData + ']');
                alert(data);
                data.addRows(data);
            }

            alert(sData);


            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(div.id));
            table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true });
```

This is adding the columns all well but not adding Rows. I have tried adding rows the following way and it works like this:

```
var rows = new Array();
rows[0] = ['1','2'];
rows[1] = ['abc', 'cdf'];
data.addRows(rows);
```

Now the problem is that i will be getting rows in the form of comma separated strings like 'abc, cdf' '1,2'. I tried converting this string into the type of string array its accepting by using .split method but it doesn't seem to work. Kindle tell me a way to make it work. Thanks

Comment: can you update your question with jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < seriesData.length; i++) {
    if (seriesData[i] != null) {
        var sData = new Array();
        sData = seriesData[i].split(',');
        /*for (a in sData) {
            sData[a] = parseInt(sData[a], 10);
        }*/
    }
    var data = JSON.parse('[' + sData + ']');
    alert(data);
    data.addRows(data);
}
```

First, you already declared a `data` variable (which holds the DataTable) above, so this line:

```
var data = JSON.parse('[' + sData + ']');
```

the `var` is ignored, and `data` is overwritten.  Second, on this line, `sData` is an array (per `sData = seriesData[i].split(',');`).  Third, since you overwrote `data`, `data` no longer has a `addRows` method when you call it on this line:

```
data.addRows(data);
```

Assuming that `seriesData[i]` is a string in the form `'foo,bar,cad'`, this is what your loop should look like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < seriesData.length; i++) {
    if (seriesData[i] != null) {
        var sData = seriesData[i].split(',');
        if (sData.length != data.getNumberOfColumns()) {
            // throw an error
        }
        else {
            data.addRows(sData);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R6Sh8/), it has update chart button to add dynamically . Below code should help you to proceed further.

```
function updateChart() {

  dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  var newData = [['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses' , 'Other'],
    ['2004',  1000,      400     ,  232   ],
    ['2005',  1170,      460    ,  421   ],
    ['2006',  660,       1120    ,  4324  ],
    ['2007',  1030,      540     ,  4234  ],
    ['2008',  1530,      50     ,    234  ]];

  // determine the number of rows and columns.
  var numRows = newData.length;
  var numCols = newData[0].length;

  // in this case the first column is of type 'string'.
  dataTable.addColumn('string', newData[0][0]);

  // all other columns are of type 'number'.
  for (var i = 1; i < numCols; i++)
    dataTable.addColumn('number', newData[0][i]);           

  // now add the rows.
  for (var i = 1; i < numRows; i++) 
    dataTable.addRow(newData[i]);            

  // redraw the chart.
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);        

 }
```

Comment: I have no idea how this will solve my simple problem